# PHP Constants (mysql parameter) and include not working

Tags: php, mysql, include, constants

when I put the follwoing 4 lines directly in a php script- the DB connection is working

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); //change these
define('DB_USER', 'bpmspace_ipms'); // to required DB
define('DB_PSWD', 'PASSWDHERE'); //connection
define('DB_NAME', 'bpmspace_ipms_v1');
```

when I copy the 4 lines in a seperated file. and try to include this file DB connection is NOT working

```
include_once('../../DB_config/login_credentials_DB_bpmspace_ipms.inc.php');
```

The error messeages in the log is

```
[Sun Jul 24 11:07:32.165303 2016] [:error] [pid 4354] [client]
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in
```

/var/www/IPMS/modules/ConnCrud.php on line 111, referer: ....

NOTE: inlcude is working - path and filename are ok . no errormessages about the include in the error.log

Is there a problem with PHP Constants and include?

in an other project I use php variables in an "external" file, and there i don't have problems to include ...  I don#t use it here becouse this is not my project...

Thanks for help rob

Comment: If you put an echo, or a die() inside the included file, can you see its effect? If no, then the file is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget `<?php` at the beginning of the included file:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); //change these
define('DB_USER', 'bpmspace_ipms'); // to required DB
define('DB_PSWD', 'PASSWDHERE'); //connection
define('DB_NAME', 'bpmspace_ipms_v1');
```

Comment: Thanks - in 1 of my 2 cases it is working now - I really forgot "<?php" and "?>" at the end
--- 
 2nd case is still not working even if the <?php  is in the externmal file 

<?php
define('HOST', 'localhost');    // The host you want to connect to.
define('USER', 'secure_login');    // The database username.
define('PASSWORD', 'PASSWDHERE');  // The database password.
define('DATABASE', 'secure_login_v2');             // The database name.
?>

include_once('../../DB_config/login_credentials_DB_secure_login.inc.php');

any hint here?

Comment: @robkuhlig IMHO the final `?>` is optional.  Now you have different define names, did you mixed up something?

Comment: Hopefully not - there are just 2 different projects coded by other people - i just try to make the include so all parameters are in the same folder.

the reason for this is that this folder is excluded via .gitignor so I do not upload the passwords etc accidentally